# Android Studio Error Code: 1 Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]

Tags: android

When I run my app I get this:
 Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]

```
Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
:app:preBuild
:app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72100Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42103Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugJava UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDexDebug
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.`

 `FAILED`

`FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.`

`* What went wrong:`
`Execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebug'.`
>` com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
    C:\Users\Ashley Windows 8\Desktop\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\build-tools\21.1.2\dx.bat --dex --output C:\Users\Ashley Windows 8\Desktop\New folder\DriversApp2\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\support-annotations-21.0.3-abef87d83d59f78493cff8c53a71ebf23a73986e.jar C:\Users\Ashley Windows 8\Desktop\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\extras\android\m2repository\com\android\support\support-annotations\21.0.3\support-annotations-21.0.3.jar`

`Error Code:
    1
Output:
    The system cannot find the path specified.
    The system cannot find the path specified.
    The system cannot find the path specified.`


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 6.951 secs`
```

My build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion '21.1.2'
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName '1.0'
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_5
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
    debug {
        debuggable true
    }
}
productFlavors {
}

}

dependencies {
// You must install or update the Support Repository through the SDK manager to use this dependency.
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
```

}

I had a error about Android Studio trying to launch a file but i had to delete it due to it being irrelevant to Android
Can anyone help me resolve this please?

When i run gradlew clean assemble --stacktrace

```
    C:\Users\Ashley Windows 8\Desktop\New folder\DriversApp2>gradlew assemble --stacktrace
`:app:preBuild                                                                    
:app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE     
:app:preDebugBuild                
:app:checkDebugManifest                
:app:preReleaseBuild                
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72100Library UP-TO-DATE      
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42103Library UP-TO-DATE      
:app:prepareDebugDependencies                 
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE      
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE      
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE      
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE      
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE      
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE      
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE      
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE      
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE      
:app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE      
:app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE      
:app:compileDebugJava UP-TO-DATE      
:app:preDexDebug   `              
`The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.`
`:app:preDexDebug FAILED          `

`FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.`

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
        C:\Users\Ashley Windows 8\Desktop\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\build-tools\21.1.2\dx.b
at --dex --output C:\Users\Ashley Windows 8\Desktop\New folder\DriversApp2\app\build\intermediates\pre-d
exed\debug\support-annotations-21.0.3-abef87d83d59f78493cff8c53a71ebf23a73986e.jar C:\Users\Ashley Windo
ws 8\Desktop\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\extras\android\m2repository\com\android\support\supp
ort-annotations\21.0.3\support-annotations-21.0.3.jar
Error Code:
        1
Output:
        The system cannot find the path specified.
        The system cannot find the path specified.
        The system cannot find the path specified.


* Try:        
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:

> >     org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebug'.
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActi
> onsTaskExecuter.java:69)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTask
> Executer.java:46)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecuti
> onAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExec
> uter.java:64)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter
> .java:58)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySou
> rceFilesTaskExecuter.java:42)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoA
> ctionsExecuter.java:52)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter
> .java:53)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOn
> ceTaskExecuter.java:43) at
> org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.executeWithoutThrowingTaskFailure(AbstractTask.java:305)
> at
> org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.executeTask(Abstra
> ctTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
>         at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(Abstra
> ctTaskPlanExecutor.java:63)
>         at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPl
> anExecutor.java:51)
>         at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:2
> 3)
>         at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java
> :88)
>         at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:29)
> 
>         at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:62)
>         at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
>         at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:68)
>         at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
>         at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:62)
>         at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:55)
>         at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:149)
> 
>         at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:106)
>         at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:86)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBui
> ldActionExecuter.java:80)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:33)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:24)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.ja
> va:36)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.ja
> va:26)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:51)
>         at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:171)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActio
> nFactory.java:237)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActio
> nFactory.java:210)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:
> 35)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:
> 24)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory
> .java:206)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory
> .java:169)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:54)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:35)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
>         at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:33)
>         at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:130)
>         at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:48)

Caused by: org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException: com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException:
 Failed to run command:



> C:\Users\Ashley Windows
> 8\Desktop\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\build-tools\21.1.2\dx.b
> at --dex --output C:\Users\Ashley Windows 8\Desktop\New
> folder\DriversApp2\app\build\intermediates\pre-d
> exed\debug\support-annotations-21.0.3-abef87d83d59f78493cff8c53a71ebf23a73986e.jar
> C:\Users\Ashley Windo ws
> 8\Desktop\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\extras\android\m2repository\com\android\support\supp
> ort-annotations\21.0.3\support-annotations-21.0.3.jar
> 
> Error Code:
>         1 Output:
>         The system cannot find the path specified.
>         The system cannot find the path specified.
>         The system cannot find the path specified.
> 
>         at org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException.throwAsUncheckedException(UncheckedException.java:39)
>         at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:66)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAc
> tion.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:235)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskActio
> n.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:211)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAc
> tion.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:222)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskActio
> n.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:200)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActio
> nsTaskExecuter.java:80)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActi
> onsTaskExecuter.java:61)
>         ... 47 more Caused by: com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run
> command:
>         C:\Users\Ashley Windows 8\Desktop\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\build-tools\21.1.2\dx.b
> at --dex --output C:\Users\Ashley Windows 8\Desktop\New
> folder\DriversApp2\app\build\intermediates\pre-d
> exed\debug\support-annotations-21.0.3-abef87d83d59f78493cff8c53a71ebf23a73986e.jar
> C:\Users\Ashley Windo ws
> 8\Desktop\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\extras\android\m2repository\com\android\support\supp
> ort-annotations\21.0.3\support-annotations-21.0.3.jar Error Code:
>         1 Output:
>         The system cannot find the path specified.
>         The system cannot find the path specified.
>         The system cannot find the path specified.
> 
>         at com.android.ide.common.internal.CommandLineRunner.runCmdLine(CommandLineRunner.java:123)
>         at com.android.ide.common.internal.CommandLineRunner.runCmdLine(CommandLineRunner.java:96)
>         at com.android.ide.common.internal.CommandLineRunner.runCmdLine(CommandLineRunner.java:76)
>         at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.preDexLibrary(AndroidBuilder.java:1339)
>         at com.android.builder.internal.compiler.PreDexCache.preDexLibrary(PreDexCache.java:119)
>         at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.preDexLibrary(AndroidBuilder.java:1273)
>         at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder$preDexLibrary$3.call(Unknown
> Source)
>         at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PreDex$PreDexTask.call(PreDex.groovy:148)
>         at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PreDex$PreDexTask.call(PreDex.groovy)

BUILD FAILED  

Total time: 36.434 secs

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>         at com.android.builder.internal.compiler.PreDexCache.createItemNode(PreDexCache.java:189)
>         at com.android.builder.internal.compiler.PreDexCache.createItemNode(PreDexCache.java:60)
>         at com.android.builder.internal.compiler.PreProcessCache.saveItems(PreProcessCache.java:486)
>         at com.android.builder.internal.compiler.PreProcessCache.clear(PreProcessCache.java:375)
>         at com.android.builder.internal.compiler.PreProcessCache$clear$0.call(Unknown
> Source)
>         at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
>         at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
>         at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:120)
>         at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$_configureProject_closure1.doCall(BasePlugin.groovy:318)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>         at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
>         at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)
>         at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:278
> )
>         at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1016)
>         at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:423)
>         at org.gradle.listener.ClosureBackedMethodInvocationDispatch.dispatch(ClosureBackedMethodInvocat
> ionDispatch.java:40)
>         at org.gradle.listener.ClosureBackedMethodInvocationDispatch.dispatch(ClosureBackedMethodInvocat
> ionDispatch.java:25)
>         at org.gradle.listener.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:83)
>         at org.gradle.listener.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:31)
>         at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyD
> ispatchAdapter.java:93)
>         at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy12.buildFinished(Unknown Source)
>         at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:111)
>         at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:86)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBui
> ldActionExecuter.java:80)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:33)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:24)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.ja
> va:36)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.ja
> va:26)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:51)
>         at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:171)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActio
> nFactory.java:237)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActio
> nFactory.java:210)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:
> 35)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:
> 24)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory
> .java:206)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory
> .java:169)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:54)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:35)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>         at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:33)
>         at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:130)
>         at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:48)
```

Comment: Post your build.gradle file

Answer (score 0):

The log output is saying you do not have Android build-tools 21 installed. Without seeing your `build.gradle` and what you have downloaded it is hard to be sure. 
Open your sdk manager, and be sure that you have the latest Android's build-tools 21 installed. Clean and build again.

Expand on this:

> I had a error about Android Studio trying to launch a file but i had to delete it due to it being irrelevant to Android

Clean > Gradle Sync > Build

---

### Edit

Try adding this yo your build.gradle dependancies:

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:20.0.0'
```

Comment: I have 17.0.0  to 21.1.2 build tools

Comment: What IDE are you using? Check the path of your sdk and make sure that sdk tools 21 is _really_ there. Sometimes that can be switched on certain updates.

Comment: Just had a look and SDK Tools 21 is definitely there,
Regarding the file I had to delete it was trying to open IEUpdate\regedit.exe which is a virus I found out,

Comment: In command line, run your build with `--stacktrace` after your run command. I am not sure what it is on Windows, but mac is `gradle assemble --stacktrace`

Comment: Now im getting this error when i run the app:
`I/O Error: C:\Users\Ashley Windows 8\Desktop\New folder\DriversApp2\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk (The system cannot find the file specified)`

Comment: Did you try to run with the stack trace? What is the path to your project? This looks like it is trying to save your apk to your desktop in a folder called `new folder`. Is your root project in `new folder\DriversApp2\`?

Comment: See my edit ^
I couldn't get it to recognize the code my bad,
Yes it did and yeah that is where i want it to be, in the .iml i have added ` <option name="APK_PATH" value="/build/apk/app-debug-unaligned.apk" />`

Comment: Change the dependency i told you to add to take version `21.0.3` instead. See if that will run.

Comment: I would like to move this to chat, but your reputation is not high enough. >:(  What gradle version are you using? (Look in your upper level build.gradle or gradle wrapper)

Comment: Stupid rep! Ha!
In my Project Stucture it is 2.2.1 but in my build.gradle its `dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'`

Answer (score 0):

See if this fixes issue for you

in \sdk\android-sdk\tools\lib\find_java.bat
replace line
`find /i "x86" > NUL && set arch_ext=32 || set arch_ext=64`
with
`find /i "x86" > NUL && set arch_ext=32||set arch_ext=64`

[Ref Source](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=75939) Response Dated 10-Dec 2014